# How do I connect my new faucet to my supply line?

Tags: faucet

I purchased a faucet with integral Flex Hoses.
One of the hoses is not long enough to reach the supply line.

The hose has a female thread swivel type fitting.
Can I purchase a Male-Female extension or is there another simple way to make the Flex Hose reach?

Comment: Does the faucet side of the hose have a standard connection? If so, I'd get a longer hose to minimize the number of connections (each one being a potential leak location).

Comment: I always end up with too much hose...

Comment: Any big box store has various length hoses for faucets/toilets that range from I think 10" to 2'.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can buy the extension flex. If I were you, I'd call the store where you bought the faucet, and they will probably have it in stock. This happens to a lot of people, but it's simple to correct